# How do Linux users test Cocos2d-x applications for Android?

Tags: android, cocos2d-x

I tried to test cocos2d-x apps on AVD but they didn't work on them. But it is necessary to check how it looks on different screens (I have only one physical device). On Windows there are Cocos Studio where you can change screen, but thre are not such thing for Linux. How do you check it ?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know whether there is a linux-version GLViewImpl or not. If it exists, you can check whether there is an API like `createWithRect(const std::string& viewName, Rect rect, float frameZoomFactor)` in this class.

- If `createWithRect` does exist, things get easier.

You can:

1. Write the screen resolution into some configuration file.
2. Read from the configuration file to get the `width` and `height` of the screen.

Then create an OpenGLView:

```
auto glview = cocos2d::GLViewImpl::createWithRect(yourTitle.c_str(), Rect(0, 0, width, height));
```

Finally set it to the director:

```
Director::getInstance()->setOpenGLView(glview);
```

In this way, when you want to test your app on different screens, you can just modify the configuration file without recompiling your source code.

- If `createWithRect` doesn't exist, you may have to use OpenGL API like `glfwSetWindowSize` to change the setting of the current OpenGLView by yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried [Genymotion Android Emulator](https://www.genymotion.com)?

It offers a lot of predefined Android devices and is much faster than the default Android emulator. Among other things, its speed comes from running x86 instead of ARM instructions, so you'll need to add x86 to the list of ABIs that your app targets. That could be as simple as adding `x86` to the end of this line in your `Application.mk` file:

```
APP_ABI := armeabi x86
```